# Django form not submitting without forms.py

Tags: html, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a Django form that does not submit. I'm using the Django base model. The following is the view for the form. I think it could be a problem with the CSRF token since it's been throwing that error, but the form itself does not submit. I'm not even making it to the 'something went wrong' error message.

```
def voting(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user=request.user
        if user.is_authenicated:
            price, created = Voting.objects.get_or_create(
                             user=request.user,
                             anonymous_user=False,
                             object_id = Object.objects.get(
            objectid=request.POST.get('objectid')
            ),
                             thumbs_up=request.POST.get('thumbs_up'),
                           thumbs_down=request.POST.get('thumbs_down'),
                             comments=request.POST.get('comments')
                              )
            price.save()
        else:
            pass
        response_data = 'success'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
   else:
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"message": "Something went wrong"}),content_type="application/json")
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="voting text-right"><small>See a problem?</small>
 <a onclick="thumbsup('{{ data.object.objectid }}'>
   <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
 </a>
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback" data-object-id="{{ data.object.objectid }}">
 <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
```

It does not work and does not submit. I keep getting a problem with the CRSF token as well.

Here is the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="feedback" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="feedback" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Feedback</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="feedback-form" action="/api/voting/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="objectid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="thumbs_up" value="False">
                    <input type="hidden" name="thumbs_down" value="True">

                    <p>We would love to hear your thoughts!</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comments">Please leave your feedback below:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" rows="3" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the form? Is it in the modal? We need to see that.

Comment: @Matthew added modal, forgot by mistake

Answer (score 0):

if it is a form validation error but you are missing capturing (this would match not submitting) then adding this to your template would highlight the cause

```
  {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{field}}
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't really have a Django form like from forms.py, will this still work. How would I implement this with a modal? Do I just add it to the modal?

Comment: You add it to your html code (the template).  Forms are an extension to views.
Your submit is the post which requires the form (however presented) to pass is_valid